# Is it possible to do windows authentication with an application hosted in the linux container?

Tags: docker, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, windows-authentication, linux-containers

I have dockerize .Net core(2.0) application hosted in the Linux container. And I want to do windows authentication with this application. I found some approaches such as creating new .Net Core Identity Service hosted in the windows container and then call from the browser this service. But I don't want to do this. This approach is the last solution I want to apply. I just want to to Windows Authentication with my host application (hosted in the linux container). Has anyone encountered such a situation before? Do you have any solution or approach?